# Can Hibernate support different datatypes on the same field?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have an SQL view that is generated by Liquibase and is mapped in Hibernate like this

```
@Entity
@Immutable
@Table(name = "VIEW_ABC")
public class ViewABC {
    ...

    @Column(name = "ATTR", columnDefinition = "ROWID")
    private String attr;

    ...
}
```

The `attr` attribute is working fine with Oracle database but there is a need for migration to Postgres, which doesn't support `rowid` datatype. There is however semi-equivalent type `ctid`.

While view generating is simple with two separate files:

Oracle: `SELECT rowid AS attr ...`

Postgres: `SELECT ctid AS attr ...`

I am unsure though how to deal with `columnDefinition` becease the application need to support both Oracle and Postgres

At this time only viable solution I can think of is to just store this as String and convert to required datatypes when used in queries.

Comment: IMHO the `columnDefinition` attribute should be removed. The `columnDefinition` attribute is only used to generate the DDL (https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Column.html#columnDefinition()) but you are using Liquibase to generate the view - you seem to never use Hibernate to generate the DDL.

Comment: If you want to define a columnDefinition so that the DB can be generated for these entities out side of liquibase but need a different type per database, you will need to have different mappings for the different databases. This is done through the use of deployment specific persistence.xml and Orm.xml files. orm.xml overrides entity annotation mappings, so this gives you the opportunity to change the type from the default. For ROWID, you can't use JPA generation you'd need a different orm.xml just for DDL generation that excludes this mapping so it isn't generated since it isn't a real column